# fgets() doesn't correctly parse the data as I want

Tags: c++, c, parsing, fgets

I'm currently parsing '.dat' file by using fgets() as below.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    FILE *fp = fopen( argv[1], "r+");   
    unsigned char pu8bufsend[256];
    printf("%s\n", argv[1]);    
    fseek(fp, 58, SEEK_SET);
    
    while(fgets((char*)pu8bufsend, 128*2, fp) != NULL)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < 256; j++)
        {        
            printf("%02x , %d\n", pu8bufsend[j], j);        
        }
    }    
    
}
```

When I parse a certain '.dat' file, the first 20 outputs look as below.

```
c0 , 0
a8 , 1
0a , 2
00 , 3
00 , 4
00 , 5
00 , 6
00 , 7
86 , 8
aa , 9
2b , 10
1d , 11
ff , 12
7f , 13
00 , 14
00 , 15
e8 , 16
7a , 17
40 , 18
00 , 19
00 , 20
```

However, I'm supposed to get this highlighted part from the '.dat' file.

[image]

It's supposed to be really simple but don't get why I'm struggling so much for this.

Can anyone figure out my problem?

Comment: One problem is that the data contains null bytes, which make `fgets()` the wrong tool for the job.  You probably need to use `fread()`; you might be able to use POSIX `getline()` if you are careful.

Comment: Is this C or C++?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've just tried fread() and still didn't work... And this is written in C++.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler. How did you know whether the data contains the null bytes?

Comment: Are the numbers seen in your picture of text (not a good idea by the way, otherwise I could quote here now....) NOT the content of the file you are trying to read? The first problematic number of those, i.e. the first which you do not get into your output, is `0x0D`, which is carriage return from point of view of `fgets()`. And the zeros Jonathan refers to are also seen there....

Comment: It's unclear what the content of your .dat file is. [Edit] your question and show us a hexadecimal dump of your file

Comment: Also show us the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Two things I noticed:

- The file contains a 0d 0a sequence, that's a `\r\n` pair, a Windows-style line ending. Your output just contains 0a, which means that line ending translation is in effect. Add "b" to the file open mode that you pass to `fopen`.
- After the line ending, your buffer contains random garbage. This is because `fgets` stops reading at a line break, and leaves the rest of the buffer as-is. You need to use `fread`. Now, in the comments you said you tried this and it "didn't work". You'll need to elaborate on this.

Comment: Part of this should be a comment....

Comment: Why? The answer to their problems is "open in binary" and "use fread". If fread doesn't work, that's really a separate problem.

Comment: ""didn't work". You'll need to elaborate on this." is the text book example of asking for clarification which should go into a comment.